# style.display doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to hide/show certain elements and it only works when I do it with the parent node and not with the child elements. Anybody knows why this happens?

```
const ulList = document.querySelector('ul');
const studentList = ulList.querySelectorAll('li');

ulList.style.display = 'none'; // (when I do it like this, everything is fine).

studentList.style.display = 'none'; // (but if I do it like these, the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" appears on the console)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did you use a `jquery` tag? This has nothing to do with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector()` returns only first matched single element but `querySelectorAll()` returns list. You have to apply style on all of the list item.
Try the following way:

```
const studentList = document.querySelectorAll('li');

studentList.forEach(function(li){
  li.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: I got what you say...but then why when I do it like this (in a loop as well), the display property to "block" doesn't take effect? The interpreter just ignores it:

const ulList = document.querySelector('ul');
const studentList = document.querySelectorAll('li');

ulList.style.display = 'none';

for (let i = 0; i < studentList.length; i += 1 ) {
if ((i + 1) >= numPage && i < y) {
          studentList[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

Comment: I am not clear about `if ((i + 1) >= numPage && i < y)`.

Comment: As I said the problem is with the `if` condition. By the way, when the `ul` is set to display none, all child `li`'s style `display='block'` is effect less and meaning less.

Answer (score 0):

I got what you say...but then why when I do it like this (in a loop as well), the display property to "block" doesn't take effect. The interpreter just ignores it:

```
const ulList = document.querySelector('ul');
const studentList = document.querySelectorAll('li');

ulList.style.display = 'none';

for (let i = 0; i < studentList.length; i += 1) {
    if ((i + 1) >= numPage && i < y) {
        studentList[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Don't pay attention to the conditional. It's part on my code. The loop and the conditional run and when the first element at 0 index receives the block property, nothings happens.

Comment: Your parent is set to display:none, right? That's the problem...  https://jsfiddle.net/1u96ag16/ There is no too much sense to set ul to display:none, in this case